# How to start new activity from onTap method in google map within Tab?

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs, android-activity

I simply have 2 tabs and used [Experience - Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) as reference.
My class Architecture is like this:
          **MainActivity**  extends TabActivity
               1.**TabGroup1Activity** extends TabGroupActivity (TabGroupActivity-class implemented from above reference)
  1.i. **Tab1Activity** extends MapActivity (which has multiple marker)
2.**TabGroup2Activity** extends TabGroupActivity
2.i. **Tab2Activity**

In second tab (Tab2Activity) i show the google map which has multiple markers. On Taping the marker i want to start new Activity under same tab without loosing tab which as at bottom.
Here is the ItemizedOverlayItem class:

**MapItemizedOverlay.java**

```
public class MapItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;



public InformationItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

    mContext = context;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {

    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

    //what code i have to write to start new activity without loosing tabs at bottom

}
}
```

I know i have to write the following code to start new activity under same tab but for above example i can not write getParent().

```
Intent in = new Intent(getParent(), TestActivity.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("in", in);
```

How do i solve this problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply pass the parent as agrgument from where you are calling "InformationItemizedOverlay".

Might be you are calling like below from some where in your code.

InformationItemizedOverlay informationItemizedOverlay = new InformationItemizedOverlay(drawable,context);

so change it as below

```
InformationItemizedOverlay informationItemizedOverlay = new InformationItemizedOverlay(drawable,context,getParent());
```

also change the constructor of "InformationItemizedOverlay" as appropriately.....

Comment: I had passed like this:  
`InformationItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new InformationItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);`